# Posting a private photo on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I'm trying to give users the possibility to upload a photo from their local drive to Facebook. I'm using [this blogpost](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)(second scenario). It works fine, but I want to make the photo automaticly "private" (or upload it to a private album).

Extra info: I use this to upload the photo to a page (user is admin, of course), not a profile.
Also: I'm planning on changing to blogpost's code to PHP SDK friendly code, so anything on setting it private using the sdk is welcome as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a user album you can do that:

When you create your album, you just have to add the privacy field (referenced here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/).

You can see the various possible values here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/

But for a page, even if you're admin, it seems you can't:

> Note: The privacy parameter only applies for posts to the user's own timeline and is ultimately governed by the privacy ceiling a user has configured for an app. It does not apply to posts made by an app on behalf of a user to another user's timelines or to Pages, events, or groups. In those cases, such posts are viewable by anyone who can see the timeline or content in the group or event.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm living on hope however since it says "[...] on behalf of a user [...] to Pages". I'm not posting on behalf of a user to a Page, I'm posting on behalve of a Page. I'm trying to add the privacy parameter, but can't seem to figure out where to put it (cf. blogpost). I'm testing it as an own-timeline-uploader for now, so it should work... Tried this, but didn't work:
`$postdata = http_build_query(
         array(
          'name' => $album_name,
          'message' => $album_description,
             'privacy' => "SELF"
            )
          ); `

Comment: try 'privacy' => "{'value':'SELF'}" (I don't know how you write json in php, maybe it's 'privacy' => ( 'value' => 'SELF')  )

Comment: `'privacy' => "{'value':'SELF'}"`worked for own-time-line-posting. Didn't work for posting on behalve of a Page :( Darn...